# Dependency conflict. Unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: reactjs, npm, dependencies, mantine

I'm creating React project and use Mantine library. When I try to install @modulz/radix-icons dependency I get error messages that there is a dependency conflict . How can I solve this problem?

Error

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: my-mantine-app@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.x || ^17.x" from @modulz/radix-icons@4.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@modulz/radix-icons
npm ERR!   @modulz/radix-icons@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\igorg\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of [@modulz/radix-icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@modulz/radix-icons) package has the below peer dependencies with semantic versions.

```
$ npm view  @modulz/radix-icons@latest peerDependencies
{ react: '^16.x || ^17.x' }
```

As you can see, it is compatible with `React ^16.x` and `React ^17.x`. Does not support `React 18.x`, the installed `react` version in your project is `18.2.0`, that's why you got this warning.

The last publish of this package is 2 years ago. So, the only safe way is to downgrade the `react` package to version `16.x` or `17.x`. Check the last version of `17.x`:

```
$ npm view react@17 version
react@17.0.0 '17.0.0'
react@17.0.1 '17.0.1'
react@17.0.2 '17.0.2'
```

Install them:

```
$ npm i react@^17.0.2 -S

$ npm i @modulz/radix-icons -S

added 1 package, and audited 6 packages in 3s

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

The warning is gone.

Note: Please be careful to run the `pm install <package>` with `--force`, or `--legacy-peer-deps` option, it will cause potentially broken. Instead, we should fix the version compatibility issues between dependent packages.

Answer (score 0):

use `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`